# Incorrect printf rounding or imprecise double?

Tags: c, pthreads, printf, double, rounding

I am using multiple pthreads to calculate pi using the following code running in each thread:

```
void *run(void *arg) {
  int *index = (int *) arg; // thread number, from 0 to thread_count - 1
  int i;
  double *partsum = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
  *partsum = 0.0;
  for (i = *index; i < NUM_STEPS; i += thread_count) {
    *partsum += 1.0 / (i * 4.0 + 1.0);
    *partsum -= 1.0 / (i * 4.0 + 3.0);
  }
  pthread_exit((void *) partsum);
}
```

The returned values from each thread are then added up to a variable `result` and printed out using printf. I get the desired output if I use printf like this (note that `result` is stored in a double):

```
printf("%.10f\n", result);
```

Moreover, the result does not change if I alter the number of threads.

Oddly enough, if I use printf like this, the result will depend on the number of running threads. It seems to get less accurate the more threads I use.

```
printf("%.15f\n", result);
```

I have come up with some of the possible reasons for this:

- As far as I know, you should not rely on the value printf outputs if you need more than 15±2 digits after the decimal point. That still does not explain why the final value changes with the thread count, though.
- It might have something to do with sizeof(void *), but this would only cause issues if I used a 32-bit machine (it would simply not allow me to cast double to void *).

I am well aware of machine representation of floating-point numbers, but I have not been to provide a feasible explanation of such behaviour.

Why does printf output different values when different thread counts are used?

Here is the main thread code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  int thread_count = atoi(argv[1]);
  pthread_t *threads = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * thread_count);
  int *args = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * thread_count);
  for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
  args[i] = i;

  for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, run, (void *) &args[i]); 
  }

  double result = 0.0;

  for (i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
    void **value = (void **)malloc(sizeof(double *));
    double **partsum;
    pthread_join(threads[i], value);

    partsum = (double **) value;
    result += **partsum;
    free(*partsum);
  }

  printf("%.15f\n", result);
}
```

Comment: We're going to need to see the code that launches the thread and that collects the returned values.  Please reread about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: After `double *partsum = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));` the memory you allocated for (curiously) a single `double` remains uninitialised, yet you proceed to add values to it. You might have been "lucky" in some circumstances that the allocated memory happened to be already zeroed, but this is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: That's a funny thing you are describing. It needs a solid proof. Well, yeah.. as @WeatherVane have identified, it is UB as presented. Fix it, and cpme back if the funny behavior persists.

Comment: @WeatherVane - good catch - could be an answer...

Comment: @WeatherVane After adding `*partsum = 0.0` the issue persists.

Comment: show the update code

Comment: Unrelated: Why do you need to `malloc` a single double? and I don't see the mentioned `result` or `printf` in the code presented.

Comment: Shouldn't `index` be used somewhere in the `run` functions? To me it seems all threads just do the same.

Comment: @EugeneSh. after the thread terminates its stack terminates too. Allocating space on the heap is a way to pass values back to the main thread.

Comment: @DmitrySerov Right, I see.

Comment: @4386427 my bad. Updated the code

Comment: Anyway, still looks like we need an MCVE.

Comment: What is the exact result in case of 10 threads and in case of 15 thread? Is the difference really just a matter of float rounding errors? Using floats for precision calculation is a scientific area in itself. Oh, and what is `NUM_STEPS`

Comment: And before blaming `printf`, grab a debugger and look at the actual value.

Comment: @EugeneSh. provided the main thread code. Looks like an MCVE to me.

Comment: @4386427 the issue is present for `NUM_STEPS` value as little as 4.

Comment: It is not an MCVE when you don't tell about `NUM_STEPS`. Anyway, I'll bet this is just rounding errors. When you increase the number of threads, you also increase `i` in the loop which may cause rounding errors to be more significant.

Comment: Floating point math is not associative. The order of evaluation the parts of the sum can change the result significantly. Also note that `double` typically has the equivalent of about 16 decimal places of precision, so finding differences in the fifteenth place is not unexpected.

Comment: How many threads? 5, 10, 20, ...?

Comment: @4386427 I tried all powers of 2 up to 32, the `result` is always different.

Comment: The bad thing here is that you allocate a local pointer `double *partsum = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));` in a function, and return it. As the pointer is defined and allocated on the local memory of the function run() you can not use it outside.

Comment: @P.Bra: No. That's complete nonsense.

Comment: A wild guess: Well, a lot years has gone by since I was lectured in numerical analysis at the university but as far as I recall one important thing was to keep numbers in as close order of magnitude as possible. In your code, you increment `i` by the number of threads. Maybe you would get better results if you divide the work differently, i.e. one thread for 0, 1, 2, ..., NUM_STEPS-1, another thread for NUM_STEPS, NUM_STEPS+1, etc.

Comment: @EOF But why is the change not significant enough to change any of the first 10-15 decimal places? Is this a 'perk' of printf or machine representation of `double`, or did I just get lucky?

Comment: This is for sure not a 'perk' of `printf`. `printf` will just print whatever you give it (rounded to the number of digits you request)

Comment: @DmitrySerov: Since you keep the subtractions matched to the additions in your `run()`-function, your code only reorders a sequence of additions of positive numbers. This tends to keep the error quite small.

Comment: @EOF I would accept that as an answer.